# In my Rails app how to encrypt my json api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I want to protect my Rails app data by encrypt my Json API response, I am using rabl gem in my app, I know there are gems to covert the rabl response to binary, but how can I add another layer of security to encrypt it.

Comment: You might find the top answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621983/rails3-paramsid-encryption useful.  It's not precisely what you're doing but it's a very good starting point.